# Vegan: Significant axes in RDA

Tags: r, vegan

I have a data frame of phytocoenological relevés:

- rows represent sites
- columns represent species

I run RDA on it using `vegan` function `rda(matrix ~ 1)`. Now I have the axes of the ordination `summary(rda)$sites`, but how to find out which of them are significant?

And my further question is, would these approaches differ if I use different ordination methods?

Thank you attention and anwers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I would say that there is no way. However, some people have suggested ways to find the number of non-significant axes. Some of these are discussed in a [vegan github issue](https://github.com/vegandevs/vegan/issues/78). My personal experience is that many of these ways work poorly: if I generate data with a defined number of dimensions + random error, methods fail to find that known number of axes. Many of these methods are easy-ish to implement (although we have not implemented them in **vegan**), though. See the discussion linked above.

Your title asks about PCoA, but your example uses RDA. However, similar methods apply to both (or fail with both like I think).